# PostgreSQL: how to concat + convert Unix epoch timestamp to date + time

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, epoch

I have a column with a timestamp. The converted column gives me a datetime value starting from the year 1975. That means I should `concat()` that value with '0' and convert it to the correct datetime.

I wrote something, and it shows me very close values, but not the same when I double-check it in browser.

Example:

```
select to_timestamp(
          cast(
             dt:double precision/1000 as bigint
          )
       ) as ts, *
from (select col1, col2, concat(timestamp, '0') as dt
      from table1
      order by col1 desc) as foo
```

For example, with the initial timestamp 168665720100, after `concat` and `to_timestamp` I get 2023-06-13 14:53:21, when it should be 2023-06-13 11:53:21.

Comment: `to_timestamp` gives you a `timestamp with time zone`, so probably the `timezone` parameter in your session is set to a time zone offset three hours from UTC. Which means that the result could correct, and all you have to do is append `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend in which `timezone` your database / session is set.

This example shows same value you posted using a different timezone: `'Australia/Brisbane'`

```
SET timezone TO 'Australia/Brisbane';

SELECT to_timestamp(1686657201000/1000);

      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2023-06-13 21:53:21+10
(1 row)
```

So, all you need to do is to set the timezone that best fit your location using `AT TIME ZONE`, e.g. `UTC`

```
SET timezone TO 'Australia/Brisbane';

SELECT to_timestamp(1686657201000/1000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';

      timezone       
---------------------
 2023-06-13 11:53:21
(1 row)
```